# create extension for anonymize failing

Tags: postgresql, masking, greenplum, anonymize

I'm interested in trying to 'anonymize' a field using static masking in Postgres Greenplum using code from this site:

https://postgresql-anonymizer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/static_masking/

The code I'm starting with this (on a Greenplum server using DBeaver query tool)

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS anon CASCADE;
SELECT anon.init() ;
```

That returns:

> "Error occurred during SQL script execution Reason:  SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "CASCADE" Position: 57

Greenplum select version()
PostgreSQL 9.4.26 (Greenplum Database 6.21.0 build commit:d0087e3b24c54d203ca8bb315559205f13cd6393) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-10), 64-bit compiled on Jun 10 2022 01:46:10

Not much on the web on this one.  Any ideas?

Was expecting some kind of success message.

Comment: Looks like you didn't install the software, or didn't install it properly.